# select xml nodes based on value of another in python xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to select a node in XML based on another nodes here is a sample of my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gameList>
    <game>
        <name>Cave Story</name>
        <lastplayed>1</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>Doom</name>
        <lastplayed>2</lastplayed>
    </game>
    <game>
        <name>Duke Nukem 3D</name>
    </game>
</gameList>
```

I have already got code to find the highest value for `<lastplayed>` and have that stored as newest but I am struggling with XPath to get the name that matches. I am using python and I should think that the XPath would be

```
//gameList/game/[lastplayed=newest]/name"
```

but when I try to get this to be output in python it doesnt seem to work.

```
import lxml.etree as ET
root = ET.parse("./gamelist.xml")
newest = 2
gname = root.xpath(".//gamelist/game/[lastplayed=newest]/name")
```

At this point I get `XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`.

I feel that there is something small that I am missing as to why this is not working for me.

Note: For simplification I have declared newest manually but this would be done by some coding that I already have in place and this XML document does get changed from another program so I can't change the order of the entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your attempt:

- `newest` in the XPath expression is not dynamic; it is not connected to the `newest` variable in your code.
- You are using syntax to look for an attribute on a tag, not for the text content *in* a tag.

As such you are looking for something with the attribute `lastplayed` being equal to `newest`. There are no such matches and your expression is incomplete.

To match `lastplayed` elements with a specific text, use `[lastplayed/text()="specific text"]`. You'll have to use Python string formatting to get the value of `newest` into that expression. You are looking for a sibling match here, so select the *parent* element where a child element text matches:

```
root.xpath(".//game[lastplayed/text()='{}']/name/text()".format(newest))
```

I've left of the `gameList` (case sensitive!) root, there is no need to limit the search to the root here.

So this looks for `<game>` elements have a `<lastplayed>` child element with your specific text. Once found, it selects the `<name>` child element, taking the text from that tag:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>> sample = '''\
... <?xml version="1.0"?>
... <gameList>
...     <game>
...         <name>Cave Story</name>
...         <lastplayed>1</lastplayed>
...     </game>
...     <game>
...         <name>Doom</name>
...         <lastplayed>2</lastplayed>
...     </game>
...     <game>
...         <name>Duke Nukem 3D</name>
...     </game>
... </gameList>
... '''
>>> root = ET.fromstring(sample)
>>> root.xpath(".//game[lastplayed/text()='{}']/name/text()".format(newest))
['Doom']
```